# D3 legend for a color scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scale

I have a color scale like this

```
var colorscale=colorbrewer['RdYlGn']['11'].reverse();
var color=d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([0,360,1600])
  .range(colorscale);
```

I'm trying to display that color scale as a legend cross the bottom of my SVG

```
function drawColorScale(){
  var pallete=svg.append('g')
    .attr('id','pallete')
  var swatch=pallete.selectAll('rect').data(colorscale);
  swatch.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('fill',function(d){
      return d;//return rgb
    })
   .attr('x',function(d,i){
     return (i*30)+'';
    })
    .attr('y',function(d,i){
      return (height-12)+'';
    })
    .attr('width','30')
    .attr('height','10');
}
```

I want to add numbers to svg rects to show the range values covered by each color.  `color.ticks(11)` returns values only up to the defined midpoint at `360`.  No matter what value I put into ticks I get back only values up to the midpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the values for each color using [invertExtent](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#quantize-scales), which:

> Returns the extent of values in the domain [x0, x1] for the corresponding value in the range: the inverse of quantize.

This is how it works, returning arrays with the bottom and top values for each color:

```js
var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([0, 1600])
  .range(d3.schemeRdYlGn['11'].reverse());

color.range().forEach(function(d){
 console.log(color.invertExtent(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a demo using your code. I separated the values and put them below the rectangles:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colorscale = d3.schemeRdYlGn['11'].reverse();
var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([0, 1600])
  .range(colorscale);

var format = d3.format(".1f")

drawColorScale();

function drawColorScale() {
  var pallete = svg.append('g')
    .attr('id', 'pallete');

  var swatch = pallete.selectAll('rect').data(colorscale);
  swatch.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return i * 50;
    })
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('width', 50)
    .attr('height', 10);

  var texts = pallete.selectAll("foo")
    .data(color.range())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("y", 80)
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return i * 50 + 25;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return format(color.invertExtent(d)[0])
    })
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", "1.3em")
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return i * 50 + 25;
    })
    .text("to")
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", "1.3em")
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return i * 50 + 25;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return format(color.invertExtent(d)[1])
    })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600"></svg>
```

Comment: PS: It seems to me that `quantize.domain()` doesn't accept a midpoint.